# Blender 2.8 interface becomes so laggy

Tags: system

I downloaded blender 2.8 a couple of weeks ago and it was working fine. Yesterday, the interface became so laggy. I'm not able to spot the issue because I didn't install a new software or something like that. Maybe I tried to install **Quick Functions** and **Power Sequencer** addons but I deleted them and the issue still presists. I also tried to load factory settings and other things but no avail.

**Version**: 2.80 (sub 37), branch: blender2.8, commit date: 2018-12-12 23:51, hash: 81ea815dcb6, type: Release
build date: 2018-12-13, 00:07:18

**Operating System :** xubuntu-18.04